I am generating pdf from html & sending it through API in formData but when I open saved file some underline and strike through text are not proper
Here is Some javascript and above it HTML code
`<div id='pdfContent'\>
<p>This is underlined text.</p>
<h1>Sample PDF Content</h1>
<p>This is strikethrough text.</p>
<h1>Sample PDF Content</h1>
<p>This is <del>strikethrough</del> text.</p>
<hr />
<p>This is some text after a horizontal rule.</p>

JAVASCRIPT CODE
const element1 = document.getElementById('pdfContent');
const options1 = {
html2canvas: {  useCORS: true, letterRendering: true },
jsPDF: { orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', compressPDF: true },
};
html2pdf().set(options1).from(element1).toPdf().get('pdf').then((pdfObj) =\> {
const perBlob = pdfObj.output('blob');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf', perBlob, pdfName);
Temp(formData);//function
}).catch(err =\> {
console.error('Error generating PDF:', err);
});
const Temp = async (formData) =\> {
const res = await UploadPDF(Id, formData);
}`

Facing issue while checking saved pdf and viewing it css issue

There's three arrow functions but the arrows look like this: =\> . T they should look like this: => .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The sentence that supposed to have been underlined needs: <u>This is underlined</u>.  and  the other sentence needs either: <s>This has been crossed out</s> or <del>This will be deleted in the final draft</del>.

If you still couldn't resolve this, alternatively can consider using 3rd party API to convert web to PDF. For example, pagesnap.co or pdfshift.
